# Call to a member function prepare() on null in postgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

File db.php:

```
<?php
class Database
{
    private $host;
    private $port;
    private $dbname;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    protected $conn;

    public function __construct($host, $port, $dbname, $user, $password) {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->port = $port;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    function error($error, $id)
    {
        echo $error.", ". $id;
        die;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $result = $this->conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$this->host port=$this->port dbname=$this->dbname user=$this->user password=$this->password");
    }
}
```

and result.php:

```
<?php

require "db.php";

    class Result extends Database
    {
        private $save;
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct("127.0.0.1", 5432, "blue", "postgres", "postgres");
        }

        public function validate()
        {
            $this->connect();
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO test (name, surname, age, active) VALUES (:name, :surname, :age, :active)';
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(':name', "Magdalena");
            $stmt->bindValue(':surname', "Blizna");
            $stmt->bindValue(':age', 29);
            $stmt->bindValue(':active', false);
            $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;

        }
    }

$save = new Result();
$save->validate();
```

I try insert element to database, but php return error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   null

Connect to databse file is OK. To connect with databse I use variable `$conn` from `db.php`.

I edit validate function.

Comment: I don't see the `connect` method called anywhere...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have in result.php file: `$save = new Result(); $save->validate();`

Comment: @michal there is no call of `connect()` in the constructor nor in `validate()`. The connection isn't established (and `$conn` is null)

Comment: @Cid I change my query I change `pg_connect` to `new PDO` and I add `$this->connect();` in `result.php` file

Comment: Add the following line after `... = new PDO(...);` in `connect()` to enable exceptions. This should give a clear error message:

`$this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: @tobain ok, I added, I have error: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "" in C:\xampp\htdocs\blue\result.php:27 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\blue\result.php(27): PDOStatement->execute() #1 `

Comment: @tobain I edit my `validate` function in my query

Comment: @tobain ok i must add `PDO::PARAM_BOOL` to: `$stmt->bindValue(':active', false, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);` now it's work ;)

Answer (score 0):

The function [`pg_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php) does not return an object like `new PDO(...)` does. It just returns a resource (an id of some sort). So you can't call the function `prepare()` on it. Instead you would have to use `pg_prepare()` like that:

```php
    $connection = pg_connect("my parameters");
    $statement = pg_prepare($connection, "some sql $1 $2");
    $result = pg_execute($connection, $statement, ["param1", "param2"]);
```

Comment: Yes I change `pg_connect` to `new PDO`, php does not return any error, but `var_dump($stmt->execute());` return `bool(false)` and nothing is saved to the database

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achive? Which problem do you want to solve?

I see Database class, which seems to be some kind of "facade" to PDO.

- Why do you need this facade, instead of using PDO directly at this point?
- Why do you inherit the Database class in Result? I don't agree that Result "IS A" Database :)

If you just want to use prepared statement, please try to use PDO directly first.
OOP is nice, but it's hard at first. You need a well defined purpose to write your own classes :)